# Minimal cut edges number in connected Eulerian graph.

Tags: graph-theory

I have to prove that Connected graph is Eulerian Graph if and only if the number of edges in minimal cut is even.

Implication from left to right. Well if $G$ is Eulerian Graph then degree of each vertex must be even. It's oblivious if i try to disconnect graph by removing all edges connected to the vertex with minimal degree. But minimal cut can be done also by dividing graph into 2 connected graphs (each graph with more then one vertex) and i have no idea how to deal with it.

Implication from right to left - completly no idea.

Comment: Does the statement "the number of edges in a minimal cut is even" mean "the number of edges in **every** minimal cut is even" or does it mean "the number of edges in **some** minimal cut is even"? I'm guessing it's "every", because there are easy examples of non-Eulerian connected graphs in which some minimal cut has an even number of edges. On the other hand, "every" makes the right-to-left implication trivial, because it implies that each vertex has even degree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right to left: If every minimal cut has an even number of edges, then in particular the degree of each vertex is even. Since the graph is connected, that means it is Eulerian.

Left to right: A minimal cut disconnects $G$ into two components $G_1$ and $G_2$. The degree sum of $G_1$ (which is even by the Handshake Theorem) = the sum of the original degrees in $G$ of the vertices of $G_1$ (which is even because $G$ is Eulerian) minus the number of edges in the minimal cut (which is therefore even, being the difference of two even numbers).

**Edit.** As pointed out in comments by @licheng and @Misha Lavrov, the right-to-left argument is nonsense; it assumes that the set of all edges containing a given vertex is a minimal cut, which is blatantly false. However, it is true in a $2$-connected graph. In general, we can argue as follows:

Let $G_1,\dots,G_k$ be the maximal $2$-connected subgraphs (blocks) of $G$ incident with a given vertex $v$. The set of all edges of $G_i$ incident with $v$ is a minimal cut of $G_i$ and also of $G$. It follows that $\deg_{G_i}(v)$ is even, and so is $\deg_G(v)=\sum_{i=1}^k\deg_{G_i}(v)$.

Comment: The justification for the proof from right to left seems insufficient. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657273/if-cardinality-of-every-minimal-cut-is-even-then-graph-is-eulerian?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @licheng The original 2014 reasoning might have been that the set of edges out of every vertex is a minimal cut. This is false: for example, in a tree, all cuts are single edges, which is bad news for higher-degree vertices. In general, we can prove that the set of edges out of $v$ is the disjoint union of several minimal cuts: for each component $G_i$ of $G-v$, the set of edges from $G_i$ to $v$ is a minimal cut. The proof still works, but I think that the more complicated argument does deserve elaboration.

Comment: @MishaLavrov It seems that a more general conclusion (awaiting proof) is that any edge-cut is the non-intersecting union of several minimal edge-cuts.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for the correction. I edited my answer. Is it OK now?

Comment: @bof I agree with the updated answer.