# If cardinality of every minimal cut is even then graph is Eulerian.

Tags: graph-theory

So I have a connected graph $G$, whose every minimal edge cut contains even number of edges. How to prove from this that the graph is Eulerian?

If I knew from this, that every vertex has even degree I would be fine, but how do I deduce this?

EDIT: I realise this question has been asked before, but why is the degree of every vertex even? The original answer doesn't elaborate on that.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632149/minimal-cut-edges-number-in-connected-eulerian-graph

Comment: I saw that, yes. But why is the degree of every vertex even is my question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was confused about the difference between minimal and minimum...